# How to convert two different CSV files into two sheets in the same Excel workbook?

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript, wincc

I have a solution which copies the csv data to excel sheet but it works for only 1 CSV file to 1 Excel sheet. How to transfer multiple CSV files to multiple sheets in Excel?

Here is my code:

```
Dim oExcel  
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")  
With oExcel  
    .DefaultSaveFormat=51  
    .Workbooks.Open sourceFile  
    .Sheets(1).Columns("A").TextToColumns .Range("A1"), , , , , True  
    .Sheets.add
    .ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs outputFile, 51  
    .Quit  
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't need to use `TextToColumns`. For the first CSV file, the sheet is already there and for the second one, you can open the file as another workbook, then use the [`Worksheet.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.copy) method to copy the sheet after the first one.

There you go:

```
Const xlWorkbookDefault = 51

Dim sourceFile1, sourceFile2, outputFile
Dim xlApp, xlWorkbook1, xlWorkbook2

sourceFile1 = "...\CSV1.csv"
sourceFile2 = "...\CSV2.csv"
outputFile = "...\output.xlsx"

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With xlApp
    Set xlWorkbook1 = .Workbooks.Open(sourceFile1)
    Set xlWorkbook2 = .Workbooks.Open(sourceFile2)
    xlWorkbook2.Sheets(1).Copy , xlWorkbook1.Sheets(1)
    xlWorkbook2.Close
    .xlWorkbook1.SaveAs outputFile, xlWorkbookDefault
    .Quit  
End With
```

---

To make it more generic, you can adjust the previous code to work with any number of CSV files:

```
Const xlWorkbookDefault = 51

Dim sourceFiles(5)
Dim outputFile
Dim xlApp, xlWorkbook1, xlWorkbook2

sourceFiles(0) = "...\CSV1.csv"
sourceFiles(1) = "...\CSV2.csv"
sourceFiles(2) = '...
' TODO: Add more files.
outputFile = "...\output.xlsx"

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With xlApp
    Set xlWorkbook1 = .Workbooks.Open(sourceFiles(0))
    For i = 1 To UBound(sourceFiles)
        Set xlWorkbook2 = .Workbooks.Open(sourceFiles(i))
        xlWorkbook2.Sheets(1).Copy , xlWorkbook1.Sheets(i)
        xlWorkbook2.Close
    Next
    .xlWorkbook1.SaveAs outputFile, xlWorkbookDefault
    .Quit  
End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much...It didn't just solve my problem but also I got ideas for my next thing in project.

Comment: I already tried to vote up but my reputation is low so i couldn't.